# Find all Key-Elements by the different value Value in Dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a two arrays I want to make a dictionary using two arrays but the problem which I am facing is that I want that duplicate value should repeat as much as It is in list. I am using this piece of code

```
text_results = ['hello', 'foo' , 'hi' , 'good' , 'this' , 'hi' ]
scores = [4,2,4,5,1,4]
dictionary = dict(zip(scores,text_result))
```

I want that output should look like this

```
[(4, 'hello'), (2, 'foo'), (4, 'hi') ,(5, 'good') ,(1, 'this'),(4, 'hi')]
```

And how can i sort it in descending order like this:

```
[(5, 'good') ,(4, 'hello'),(4, 'hi'), (4, 'hi'), (2, 'foo') ,(1, 'this')]
```

Comment: But that is a list of tuples and you are asking to make a dictionary? Please make sure what it is you are really wanting to do.

Comment: "*But the problem which I am facing is that I want that duplicate value should repeat as much as It is in list. I am using this piece of code*", that sentence is unclear to me...

Comment: What you describe is a list, you can use: `list(zip(scores,text_results))`, or in Python-2.x, more simpler `zip(scores,text_results)`...

Comment: Means that duplicate value should repeat as much time it occur in the dictionary

Comment: It doesn't seem to make much sense to have score as key in your dict. Shouldn't score be the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you should use list, not dictionary.

```
text_results = ['hello', 'foo' , 'hi' , 'good' , 'this' , 'hi' ]
scores = [4,2,4,5,1,4]
res_list = list(zip(scores,text_results)) 
print res_list
```

Comment: But what if i want to arrange it by ascending according to scores?

Comment: @AliJafar `sorted(res_list)`.  descending: `sorted(res_list, reverse=True)`.

Comment: Thanks @ZevAverbach

Answer (score 2):

## sorted tuples

If you want a list of sorted tuples, you can just sort them with `sorted` and a reverse order :

```
print(sorted(zip(scores, text_results), reverse=True))
# [(5, 'good'), (4, 'hi'), (4, 'hi'), (4, 'hello'), (2, 'foo'), (1, 'this')]
```

## values as lists

If you really want a `dict`, your values could be lists. Python dicts are unordered, though :

```
text_results = ['hello', 'foo' , 'hi' , 'good' , 'this' , 'hi' ]
scores = [4,2,4,5,1,4]

table = {}

for name, score in zip(text_results, scores):
    if not table.get(name):
        table[name] = []
    table[name].append(score)

print(table)
# {'this': [1], 'hi': [4, 4], 'foo': [2], 'hello': [4], 'good': [5]}
```

This way, if you want the values for `hi`, you can get them directly without having to iterate over a list:

```
>>> table.get('hello')
[4]
>>> table.get('hi')
[4, 4]
>>> table.get('not_here')
>>>
```

Note that this functionality is provided by [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `defaultdict(list)`. I sometimes find the extra output distracting, though:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'this': [1], 'hi': [4, 4], 'foo': [2], 'hello': [4], 'good': [5]})
```

Answer (score 1):

A **dictionary can map a key to only one value**. So you cannot construct a this as a *vanilla* dictionary. There are some options:

1. you work with a list (in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) with `zip(..)`, in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) with `list(zip(..))`):

   ```
   >>> zip(scores,text_results)
   [(4, 'hello'), (2, 'foo'), (4, 'hi'), (5, 'good'), (1, 'this'), (4, 'hi')]
   ```
2. you work with a `MultiDict`, you can for instance install [`werkzeug`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict):

   ```
   $ pip install werkzeug
   ```

   and then you can use the multidict:

   ```
   from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict
   d = MultiDict(zip(scores,text_results))
   ```

   you can then use `.getlist(key)` to obtain a list of values associated with a key, for example:

   ```
   >>> d.getlist(4)
   ['hello', 'hi', 'hi']
   >>> d.getlist(2)
   ['foo']
   ```
3. you can use a `defaultdict` and build the dictionary that maps to a list yourself:

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict

   d = defaultdict(list)
   for k,v in zip(scores,text_results):
       d[k].append(v)
   ```

Comment: This is cool, hadn't heard of the MultiDict.  What's the advantage compared to a `defaultdict(list)`?

Comment: @ZevAverbach: I think the fact that it provides a nice interface that enables you to still work with keys that are mapped to values. For instance a lookup `d[key]` will give the first value associated to the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this output : `[(4, 'hello'), (2, 'foo'), (4, 'hi') ,(5, 'good') ,(1, 'this'),(4, 'hi')]`
Then it is not a dictionary in python meaning. The dictionary in python use `{}`.
What you call "dictionary" is a list, each element being a tuple.
So you should just create a list, and add a tuple for each iteration of your text or score list :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_results = ['hello', 'foo', 'hi', 'good', 'this', 'hi']
    scores = [4, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4]
    my_own_container = []
    for i in range(len(text_results)):
        my_own_container.append(tuple((scores[i], text_results[i])))
    print(my_own_container)
```

Comment: What if I want to arrange it according to scores in ascending order?

Comment: @AliJafar Maybe you should add some context of your work in your question. But I think sort is magical enough to solve your problem.